# Show that the length of a basis of a space must be equal to that spaces dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for a nice and simple proof for the following:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $K$. The length of any basis of that space must be equal to $\dim V$ (i.e. a set of vectors $\mathbf{v}=\{\vec{v}_1,\cdots ,\vec{v}_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ iff $n=\dim V$ and $\mathbf{v}$ is linearly independent).

**HOWEVER,** I'm looking for a proof that does not involve the rank-nullity theorem, nor makes any reference to matrix representations and manipulations, or at least direct references to it. Also, it would be nice if the proof didn't involve breaking up the space into the direct sum of a subspace spanned by a list of vectors of length less than $\dim V$ and its orthogonal complement, thus proving by contradiction.

Basically I'm looking for a short and elegant proof of the following statement that abides by the conditions stated above. For example, in S. Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*, a beautiful proof that every operator on a finite-dimensional vector space over the field of complex numbers has at least one eigenvalue **without** making a reference to determinants.

Could you provide one?

Comment: What you're trying to prove is referred to as the [dimension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces).  You might like the second proof provided on the wiki page.

Comment: How are you defining the dimension of a vector space if not as the number of elements in a basis?

Comment: Gahhh I didn't think about that @SantiagoCanez. I see the point in Omnomnomnom's comment though - his response concerns a nearly identical theorem/statement.